# True/False: Multivariable Calculus Limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

\begin{align}
1. & \text{ If } \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x, y) = 0, \text{ then } \lim_{x\to0}f(x, 0) = 0. \\[10pt]
2. & \text{ If } \lim_{x\to0}f(x, 0) = 0, \text{ and } \lim_{y\to0}f(0, y) = 0, \text{ then } \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x, y) = 0.
\end{align}

I think both are true, but I'm not exactly sure how to prove it (or disprove it if I'm wrong). I understand that for a limit to exist in space, the limit value L must be the same when approached from all directions. However, I don't think I have an intuitive grasp of how to think about this problem.

Comment: Condition $2$ says that the limit exists in **two** different directions. Is two all?

Comment: (1) is true, but (2) is not. When it says $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0),$ it means any sequence of points $(x_{n},y_{n})$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_{n},y_{n})=(0,0),$ so this is true also for a sequence with $y_{n}=0$ for all $n$. For (2), consider $f(x,y)=1$ if $xy\neq0,$ $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: the first one is correct. if the limit exist it is the only one so every direction you will take will lead to the same limit. however, the second one is not always true, since there are infinite directions you can take showing two of them is not enough.

Comment: 2) consider $\frac {xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: @segevp So essentially the idea in 1) is that: Given the first condition we know the limit exists, so when we approach along any direction (like the x-axis as is stated), the limit must be the same. 

And 2) is false because only giving two directions, like the x and y axes as they do, is not enough to prove it exists.

Comment: @Jake correct. tip: usually when you are given a function and you want to show the limit in unique you should use squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The condition establishes that regardless of your path the limit is $0$, so it's easy to see that the path $y=0 \;x\to 0$ is also $0$, so true.

2) The condition is giving just particular paths not all the paths, so you cannot say that the limit exists, so false.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(x,y)$ is expressed in polar coordinates as $(x,y) = r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta).$ Let $f(x,y)= \sin(2\theta).$ Then $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f(x,0) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to0} f(0,y) = 0$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f(x,x) = 1,$ so $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$ cannot exist.

Suppose $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y) = 0.$ Then $f(x,y)$ can be made as close as desired to $0$ by making $(x,y)$ close enough, but not equal, to $0.$ Among the points $(x,y)$ that are close enough are those of the form $(x,0)$ if $x$ is close enough to $0.$ Therefore the first proposition is true.

Comment: @Anonymous : The first one, as now written, is true. I misread it the first time, but then I realized what it actually says.